# Метасмиволы в /etc/sudoers

Tags: linux

Подскажите, можно ли средствами метасимволов в /etc/sudoers разрешить выполнение юзером некоторой команды с флагами? То есть в данный момент в /etc/sudoers есть запись вида "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/cmd -param1 value". Можно ли как-то дать юзеру возможность запускать команду с произвольным количеством флагом, помимо того, который уже разрешен?

Comment: да просто не указывайте вообще никаких опций и параметров. в чём проблема-то?

Comment: В том, что параметр "-param1 value" в данном случае обязателен. К примеру, я хочу, чтобы пользователь мог выполнять journalctl -u testunit. Но если я добавлю в sudoers "ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/journalctl -u testunit", то юзер не сможет использовать флаги journalctl. Например, комнда "journalctl -u testunit --since 10m" работать не будет.

Comment: ну, скрипт сделайте, который будет вызывать journalctl с нужным вам параметром, добавляя всё остальное, что ему передано.

Comment: Да, рассматривал такой вариант, но показалось, что есть шанс справиться средствами метасимволов в /etc/sudoers. В любом случае спасибо)